# retrieve values from interpolation object

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am doing interpolation using scipy

```
import scipy.interpolate
x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)
f = sp.interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
```

here, I am gettng f as object. but, what If I need values of that object f?
how can I retrieve values from that interpolation object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html):

```
xnew = np.arange(0,9, 0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)   # use interpolation function returned by `interp1d`
```

You can evaluate it for any values:

```
x0 = 3.1
y0 = f(x0)
```